# An better way to include head/footer with node/express?

Tags: node.js, express, fs-extra

On the occasion when we are using fs.write rather than fs.render and want to include a header and a footer with our output.  I tried using include and it gives an error.

> Lines like this do not work ->
>   const head = require('../views/partials/production-header.html');

```
async function readInFile(theFile) {
  return await fs.readFile(path + theFile)
}

router.get('/:qry', function(req, res) {

  readInFile('/views/partials/production-header.html').then(data => {
    let head = data.toString()
    readInFile('/views/partials/production-footer.html').then(data => {
      let foot = data.toString()


        display_page(head, foot)
      })
    })
 })

 function display_page(head,foot,filter) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(head);
    res.write(q);
    res.write(foot);
    res.end();
 }
```

the above works but hardly seems like the best way to go about it

Comment: Why not to use **template engine** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of template engines for that, and is really easy to use, for example [pug](https://pugjs.org) and you can find an integration tutorial with express [here](https://pugjs.org/api/express.html)

Comment: Thanks that link was helpful.